# Facebook Debugger lint tool gets HTTP 206 - doesn't detect Open Graph meta tags (others tools do)

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

I believe my site has the correct markup for Facebook & Open Graph meta tags. But checking Facebook's linter shows that none of the tags are being detected. You can see for yourself here:

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=goodloesolitaire.com

When I use a different site, the tags are found:

http://www.opengraph.in/?url=goodloesolitaire.com&format=html

I went through the similar questions and none of those check out. Any ideas on why Facebook's debugger might see nothing?

Answer (score 4):

Facebook is seeing HTTP code 206 "Partial Content" instead of normal 200 "OK".

> 206 "Partial Content": This message might occur if a client has a
>   partial copy of content in its cache and requests and update of missing
>   content. This message indicates that the partial request succeeded.

I found one old forum post about it: http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=68440

It looks like it might be a server configuration issue to do with caching. Do you run Varnish or anything like that on your server? Check in to that.

Another thing to try might be to move your charset meta tag below your Open Graph tags, so Facebook knows the right encoding to parse them with. Also, using this type tag might work better:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Finally, make sure you don't have anything blocking the Facebook scraper user agent. As mentioned in their [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/best-practices/):

> Our bot functions with the User Agent "facebookexternalhit/*". Make
>   sure you're not blocking that user agent. Also, make sure Facebook's
>   servers can reach your server.

Comment: The 206 was a clue. It turned out to be a problem with Connect middleware framework. It was setting Content-Length based on the requested range rather than body size.

Comment: You might want to accept this answer if it helped solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

If You are using Varnish:

Put

```
if (req.http.user-agent ~ "facebookexternalhit")
{
  return(pipe);
}
```

Inside your `sub vcl_recv`:

```
sub vcl_recv
{
}
```

It worked very well.

Answer (score 0):

We use Varnish so this did the trick for us:

```
if (req.http.user-agent ~ "facebookexternalhit")
    {
    return(pipe);
    }
```

https://www.varnish-cache.org/lists/pipermail/varnish-misc/2011-February/020060.html