# URL linter gives "206 Partial Content"

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, varnish, partial

I have an issue with the like button for my website. Facebook URL Linter gives me a 206 Partial Content for this page http://www.vagabond-crew.com/crew

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.vagabond-crew.com%2Fcrew

And I don't know why.

PS. I have varnish but for this website : vagabond-crew.com but I set Varnish to pass all requests :

```
    if (req.http.user-agent ~ "facebookexternalhit") {
            return(pipe);
    }
```

Comment: related post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8492528/facebook-debugger-lint-tool-gets-http-206-doesnt-detect-open-graph-meta-tags

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the og:description meta tag

```
<meta property="og:description" content="Your site's description" />
```

**EDIT**: and also edit your `<html>` tag

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="fr" lang="fr" dir="ltr">
```

Good luck! ;)

Comment: Thanks Luis, but it doesn't fix the issue : https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.vagabond-crew.com%2Fcrew ... Have you any other idea plz ? :)