# og:image is not being fetched correctly by Facebook on liking or sharing

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I'll try to be direct explaining my problem:

When liking/sharing an article from my website (http://www.radiopico.com) og:image does not work well (you can try with this url for example:http://www.radiopico.com/index.php?n=noticias&menu=noticias&id_noticia=14350)

- on the debugger I always get the corret image url
- It never shows the image
- If I click the image I get a not found error.. if I copy the url and past it on the address bar I get the image
- Sometimes it says image is to small.. it is wrong, because it is very larger then the minimum sizes facebook encourage. Also there is no ratio problem
- When I try to post the address on facebook it never shows the picture
- I have tried to add a time var (?T=...) after the address to make sure it is not caching
- I have put multiple og:images.. still does not works.
- I have read and tried all the "tricks" I find here (Stackoverdlow) or on google

Thanks for your support and best wishes on resolving this mystery

Comment: I can't reproduce this with http://www.radiopico.com/index.php?n=noticias&menu=noticias&id_noticia=14350 - I always get an image of gun, and there are no warnings in the linter. It works fine in both the composer and news feed when I post it. Is there still an issue?

Comment: Yes, I still have problems.
Example: this article is from today:
http://www.radiopico.com/index.php?n=noticias&menu=noticias&id_noticia=14365 

- if I post the url on facebook it won't get the photo
- if you debug it I get the photo

Seems hopeless... can't get this

Comment: images come fine for me, when I try to share. And make sure the 'og:url' tag in your page has "&" escaped properly, as facebook linter lints that, not the main url.

Answer (score 0):

I notice that your image is technically not defined at 72 dpi, but rather at 300 dpi:

[image: Screenshot of the Image Size dialog box when image is opened Photoshop.]

I cannot say definitively that this would cause your problem. Browsers are generally smart enough to display an image at 72 dpi (using the pixel dimensions) regardless of the "Resolution" that is defined within the image. However, it might be worth re-saving the image with the resolution correctly set for the web at 72dpi. Perhaps Facebook is getting confused about the image size due to the resolution setting.

Also, just to eliminate potential problems with the image, if you have Photoshop, use the Save for Web command to re-save the image, which will automatically define the re-saved image at 72dpi AND save it without a built-in preview, which you should always do for the web anyway to reduce file size. Then try again. Again, I'm not sure that these suggestions will work, but it seems like a good idea to eliminate the resolution, embedded preview and potential issues with the original file by re-saving.

Comment: Thanks, but even if this was an issue to this particular photo, I have  hundreds of photos with 72 dpis...
Example: http://www.radiopico.com/index.php?n=noticias&menu=noticias&id_noticia=14365 the photo of this article opens on the debuger and does not open on facebook when I link to the page

Answer (score 0):

Debuging your [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8492528/facebook-debugger-lint-tool-gets-http-206-doesnt-detect-open-graph-meta-tags)

I see linter response is 206.

I don't know if it can help u but I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8492528/facebook-debugger-lint-tool-gets-http-206-doesnt-detect-open-graph-meta-tags)

check it out ;)