# HTTP Status Code 206: When should it be used?

Tags: facebook, http, http-headers, facebook-opengraph, varnish

The [206 status code](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.2.7) (w3.org) indicates a partial result in response to a request with a `Range` header.

So "clearly" if the requested document is e.g. 1024 bytes long, and the `Range` header is `bytes=0-512` then a status code of `206 Partial Content` should be returned. (Assuming that the server is able to return the content)

BUT what if the `Range` is `bytes=0-2000`?
Should `200 OK` or `206 Partial Content` be returned?
It seems to me that this isn't clearly defined in the specification -- or maybe I'm not reading the right place?

**Why do I care?**
I ask because the [Varnish Cache](https://www.varnish-cache.org/) seems to always return `206 Partial Content`, whereas the [Facebook Open Graph debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) seems to expect `200 OK`. [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9807771/facebook-debugger-response-206)] [[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8492528/facebook-debugger-lint-tool-gets-http-206-doesnt-detect-open-graph-meta-tags)]

*Example*: GET request to Varnish
(I receive the full document, and yet `206 Partial Content` is returned)

```
> curl --dump-header - -H 'Range: bytes=0-7000' https://www.varnish-cache.org/sites/all/themes/varnish_d7/logo.png
HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
Server: nginx/1.1.19
Date: Mon, 14 Apr 2014 22:43:31 GMT
Content-Type: image/png
Content-Length: 2884
Connection: keep-alive
Last-Modified: Thu, 15 Dec 2011 12:30:46 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
X-Varnish: 1979866667
Age: 0
Via: 1.1 varnish
Content-Range: bytes 0-2883/2884
```

Further w3 reference: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't matter. Both replies are valid.

(also note that the current specification is now http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/draft-ietf-httpbis-p5-range-26.html, to be published as RFC soon)

Comment: But how do you now that it doesn't matter? It seems to me that the specification is not clear on this, and whether it should return one or the other is "undefined" -- a hole in the specification

Comment: I know that it doesn't matter because I'm one of the authors of that specification, and if it *did* matter, we would tell you.

Comment: could we agree that it is an error in the debugger then