# Getting Response code 206 in facebook debugger?

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-opengraph, http-response-codes

I am building a wordpress blog and using yoast seo plugin which automatically integrates the open graph, and on debugging my url i got..

```
 Time Scraped   2 seconds ago
 Response Code  206
 Fetched URL    http://www.fizzxo.com/will-tigers-taste-kiwis-time-overview-   predictions-squad-many/
 Canonical URL  http://www.fizzxo.com/will-tigers-taste-kiwis-time-overview-predictions-squad-many/ (42 likes, shares and comments More Info )
 Server IP  52.53.254.185
```

so can someone tell why i am getting this and not **200**?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

> 206 Partial Content

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Facebook does not need the whole Page to get the Open Graph tags.

More information:

- https://serverfault.com/questions/571554/what-does-http-code-206-partial-content-really-mean
- [HTTP Status Code 206: When should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23072192/http-status-code-206-when-should-it-be-used)