# Nginx return 206 when serve mp4

Tags: nginx

I used nginx to serve mp4 files. When my request didn't contain 'Range' in header, Nginx returns 200 status code. I only want it return 206 status. Currently I have to rewrite the request to a nodejs server to serve 206. Any nginx config for this problem ?

Comment: If there's a `Range` header, 200 or 206 [would both be acceptable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23072192/http-status-code-206-when-should-it-be-used). If there *isn't* a `Range` header, 206 is not a valid response. Fix the client.

Comment: @Joe I met a react player it loaded full video before play mp4. It looks strange