# facebook debugger tools does not scrape correct data

Tags: facebook, debugging, facebook-graph-api

around a year ago I make a php script to `echo` the description and title and image to be loaded in `meta tag`.

I also used facebook `og:image, og:description` in `meta property` and it works. there used to be some problems but I just need to copy paste the URL into facebook debugger, click debug and scrape again and it is fixed.

now those steps does not fixes my issue, I have checked the echoed description and image from Chrome's `view-source` and it returns the correct strings

the problem is when I copy paste the URL into debugger, the RAW data, one of it is correct while the other is not, and the OG properties that constructed is even worse.

**this is the view-source from chrome**

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8'>
<meta property="og:description" content=" Dapatkan kesempatan menjadi dealer/reseller mesin fotocopy kami dengan harga yang murah terjangkau">
 <meta property="og:image" content="http://images.rajafotocopy.com/raja.png">
```

**this is the RAW data from facebook**

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<meta property="og:description" content=" PT.Buana Citra Abadi Sewa mesin fotocopy & Jual Mesin Fotocopy new/rekondisi murah import hub : 0815 7813 8888" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://images.rajafotocopy.com/raja.png" />
<meta name="webcrawlers" content="all" />
<meta name="rating" content="general" />
<meta name="spiders" content="all" />
```

**this is the constructed OG properties**

```
 og:description PT.Buana Citra Abadi Sewa mesin fotocopy & Jual Mesin Fotocopy new/rekondisi murah import hub : 0815 7813 8888
 og:image   http://headers.rajafotocopy.com/cibo.png
```

now please look at `og:description` and `og:image`, in **view source** the `og:description` and `og:image` shows the correct strings.

but in **RAW data** only the `og:image` is correct.

and in **constructed og properties** both are wrong.

From this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8492528/facebook-debugger-lint-tool-gets-http-206-doesnt-detect-open-graph-meta-tags) I think it is because of the `code 206`, the partial content loaded. so how do I force facebook to scrape fully, not partially? the link to that forum cannot be reached anymore. from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9807771/facebook-debugger-response-206#answer-9807896) it says `code 206` it shouldn't be a problem?

Comment: No, 206 should not be a problem. You should set `og:url` as well. Do you have an example URL were we can check the issue?

Comment: yes this one https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=http%3A%2F%2Frajafotocopy.com%2Fjawa%2Freseller.html

Comment: See this in debug tool output: “Canonical URL: `http://rajafotocopy.com/jawa/store`” - by setting the wrong canonical URL you yourself told Facebook, "the real address for this is not `http://rajafotocopy.com/jawa/reseller.html`, but `http://rajafotocopy.com/jawa/store`, so please go and fetch the meta data from the latter." If you need canonical set to the first URL, then at least specify the actual URL of the page using `og:url`.

Comment: ah I see. so that's the problem, I can just remove the canonical url then